# Why does my compiler warn me about gets but not about scanf?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

If I compile a code with `gets`, the compiler outputs a warning saying that the function shouldn't be used:

```
<source>:5:13: warning: 'char* gets(char*)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     gets(buf);
             ^
In file included from <source>:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:577:14: note: declared here
 extern char *gets (char *__s) __wur __attribute_deprecated__;
              ^
/tmp/ccWRqB1K.o: In function `main':
/home/ce/<source>:5: warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

However, if I replace `gets` with `scanf` and a `%s` format string, it does not output such a warning:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[10];
    scanf("%s",buf);
}
```

If this program is compiled and I provide an input larger than 10 bytes, the program segfaults, and the buffer is overflown.

How can I understand this difference? Is `scanf` considered safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `scanf` is *not considered a safe function*. It can be used safely or unsafely. In this case, your compiler is not issuing a warning since it does not have a lint that for an unbounded "%s" format string - i.e. it does not know that you are using it unsafely. On the other hand, it is hardly possible to use `gets` safely, as there is *no way to provide a buffer length*, so your compiler can with high confidence determine that you should not be using it.

To use `scanf` safely in your example, you'd need to provide the length in the format string, like so:

```
char buf[10];
scanf("%9s", buf);
```

The buffer needs to be one byte larger than the length specifier in the format string to accomodate for the terminating NUL byte.

Comment: thanks I was a little confuse because in all the examples of buffer over flow they use gets

Comment: FWIW, `gcc` after 5.5 does not support `gets` anymore: https://godbolt.org/z/zxdbY3

Comment: @daniel Yes, `gets` is a typical one, but there are a lot of different ways you can get a buffer overflow. More tricky buffer overflows can be quite hard to spot!